# How to filter empty or NULL names in a QuerySet?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, filter, null

I have `first_name`, `last_name` & `alias` (optional) which I need to search for. So, I need a query to give me all the names that have an alias set.

Only if I could do:

```
Name.objects.filter(alias!="")
```

So, what is the equivalent to the above?

Answer (score 1116, accepted):

You could do this:

```
Name.objects.exclude(alias__isnull=True)
```

If you need to exclude null values *and* empty strings, the preferred way to do so is to chain together the conditions like so:

```
Name.objects.exclude(alias__isnull=True).exclude(alias__exact='')
```

Chaining these methods together basically checks each condition independently: in the above example, we exclude rows where `alias` is either null *or* an empty string, so you get all `Name` objects that have a not-null, not-empty `alias` field. The generated SQL would look something like:

```
SELECT * FROM Name WHERE alias IS NOT NULL AND alias != ""
```

You can also pass multiple arguments to a single call to `exclude`, which would ensure that only objects that meet *every* condition get excluded:

```
Name.objects.exclude(some_field=True, other_field=True)
```

Here, rows in which `some_field` *and* `other_field` are true get excluded, so we get all rows where both fields are not true. The generated SQL code would look a little like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Name WHERE NOT (some_field = TRUE AND other_field = TRUE)
```

Alternatively, if your logic is more complex than that, you could use Django's [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#q-objects):

```
from django.db.models import Q
Name.objects.exclude(Q(alias__isnull=True) | Q(alias__exact=''))
```

For more info see [this page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/) and [this page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets) in the Django docs.

<sub>As an aside: My SQL examples are just an analogy--the actual generated SQL code will probably look different. You'll get a deeper understanding of how Django queries work by actually looking at the SQL they generate.</sub>

Comment: I believe that your edit is wrong: Chaining filter does NOT automatically create an SQL `OR` (only in this case), it produces an SQL `AND`.
See this page for reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#chaining-filters
The advantage of chaining is that you can mix `exclude` and `filter` to model complicated query conditions.

If you want to model a real SQL `OR` you must use a Django Q object: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

Please edit your edit to reflect this, as the answer is severely misleading as it stands.

Comment: @shezi: I meant it more as an analogy--I didn't mean that the actual SQL code is guaranteed to use an `OR` to fuse the conditions. I'll edit my answer to clarify.

Comment: Keep in mind that there are at different ways to represent this logic--for instance, `NOT (A AND B)` is equivalent to `NOT A OR NOT B`. I think that makes things confusing to new Django developers who know SQL but are unfamiliar with ORMs.

Comment: I know De Morgan's law, and this is my point exactly: Your example only works because it takes advantage to turn the `AND` in the first query into an `OR` because you're using `exclude`. In the general case, it's probably more correct to think of chaining as a `THEN`, i.e. `exclude(A) THEN exclude(B)`.

Sorry about the harsh language above. Your answer really is good, but I'm worried about new developers taking your answer too generally.

Comment: @shezi: Fair enough. I agree that it's better to think of it in Django terms and not in SQL terms, I just thought that presenting chaining in terms of `AND` and `OR` might be useful for someone coming to Django from an SQL background. For a deeper understanding of Django, I think the docs do a better job than I can.

Comment: It all becomes tough when you have a related table and want to filter records that have acolumn=FALSE or when the related record is not even existing in the table. You need NOT EXIST query, but... Django (even the latest version 4.1.3) has fucked up ~Q() function. It gets crazy about missing table aliases.

Comment: In case the field is Array. I used this: `Name.objects.exclude(alias__isnull=True).exclude(alias__exact=[])`

Answer (score 75):

```
Name.objects.filter(alias__gt='',alias__isnull=False)
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think the `alias__isnull=False` condition is redundant. If the field is `Null` surely it will be excluded by the first clause?

Comment: Aside from my earlier comment/question I think the positive logic here is easier to follow than in some of the other answers.

Comment: @Bobble that would depend on the database implementation -- [ordering is delegated to the databse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#latest)

Comment: `alias__gt` was the only thing that worked for JSON type columns where I wanted to exclude empty strings from JSON like `{'something:''}`. So working syntax is: `jsoncolumnname__something__gt=''`

Comment: this is super answer if you only have to do a positive check!

Comment: This is a brilliant answer! I needed this for `limit_choices_to` and could not use `.exclude`.

Answer (score 42):

Firstly, the Django docs strongly recommend not using NULL values for string-based fields such as CharField or TextField. Read the documentation for the explanation:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#null

Solution:
You can also chain together methods on QuerySets, I think. Try this:

```
Name.objects.exclude(alias__isnull=True).exclude(alias="")
```

That should give you the set you're looking for.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to exclude null (`None`), empty string (`""`), as well as a string containing white spaces (`"  "`), you can use the `__regex` along with `__isnull` filter option

```
Name.objects.filter(
    alias__isnull = False, 
    alias__regex = r"\S+"
)
```

`alias__isnull=False` excludes all the columns null columns

`aliax__regex = r"\S+"` makes sure that the column value contains at least one or more non whitespace characters.

Answer (score 8):

**1. When using exclude, keep the following in mind to avoid common mistakes:**

Should **not** add **multiple** conditions into **an** `exclude()` block like `filter()`. To exclude multiple conditions, you should use **multiple** `exclude()`.

Example: `(NOT a AND NOT b)`

```
Entry.objects.exclude(title='').exclude(headline='')
```

equal to

```
SELECT... WHERE NOT title = '' AND NOT headline = ''
```

======================================================

**2. Only use multiple when you really know about it:**

Example: `NOT (a AND b)`

```
Entry.objects.exclude(title='', headline='')
```

equal to

```
SELECT.. WHERE NOT (title = '' AND headline = '')
```

Comment: Are you sure about the above to statement?

Comment: The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#exclude) are pretty clear that you can include multiple conditions within an `.exclude()` but that they work differently then separate ones.  It's the same as the difference between `NOT (a AND b)` and `(NOT a AND NOT b)`.

Comment: Thank you; I've made the necessary changes.

Answer (score 5):

From Django 1.8,

```
from django.db.models.functions import Length

Name.objects.annotate(alias_length=Length('alias')).filter(alias_length__gt=0)
```

Comment: This seems like a "something you *can* do", not something you *should* do. It significantly blooms the query complexity over two simple checks.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply do this:

```
Name.objects.exclude(alias="").exclude(alias=None)
```

It's really just that simple.  `filter` is used to match and `exclude` is to match everything but what it specifies.  This would evaluate into SQL as `NOT alias='' AND alias IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: This is incorrect. The question aims to exclude empty (`alias=""`) and NULL (`alias=None`) aliases from the query. Yours would include instances with `Name(alias=None)`.

Comment: @damon - I was answering what was the equivalent to `.filter(alias!="")` but not the title.  I've edited my answer.  However, character fields shouldn't allow NULL values and use the empty string for a non-value (as per convention).

Answer (score 3):

Another approach using a generic `isempty` lookup, that can be used with any field.

It can also be used by django rest_framework or other apps that use django lookups:

```
from distutils.util import strtobool
from django.db.models import Field
from django.db.models.lookups import BuiltinLookup

@Field.register_lookup
class IsEmpty(BuiltinLookup):
    lookup_name = 'isempty'
    prepare_rhs = False

    def as_sql(self, compiler, connection):
        sql, params = compiler.compile(self.lhs)
        condition = self.rhs if isinstance(self.rhs, bool) else bool(strtobool(self.rhs))
        if condition:
            return "%s IS NULL or %s = ''" % (sql, sql), params
        else:
            return "%s <> ''" % sql, params
```

You can then use it like this:

```
Name.objects.filter(alias__isempty=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

this is another simple way to do it .

```
Name.objects.exclude(alias=None)
```

Comment: `None` is not the same thing as `""`.