# How do I query for this in Django?

Tags: python, mysql, database, django

```
| random_code         | varchar(200)  | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |

MyTable.objects.filter(random_code = None)
```

Is this correct?  Will this SELECT where there is no random code set?  Above is my table.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Filtering for empty or NULL names in a queryset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/844556/filtering-for-empty-or-null-names-in-a-queryset)

Answer (score 1):

If you ever want to see what your `QuerySet` as SQL you can use `QuerySet.query.as_sql()` to return the SQL statement as a string.

Answer (score 1):

This has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844556/django-filter-how-do-i-go-about-filtering-for-emply-or-null-names-in-a-queryse/844572#844572).  Basically you do this:

```
MyTable.objects.filter(random_code__isnull=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition of Jason Webb's answer you could do something like:

```
MyTable.objects.filter(random_code__isnull=True).exclude(random_code='')
```

to exclude variants which have empty string.