# Django query to find model instances where somefilefield == None?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Given the model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    resume = models.FileField(upload_to='resumes/', blank=True, null=True)
```

I have created a few people via:

```
Person.objects.create(name='Brad')
Person.objects.create(name='Tony')
```

How do I write a query using the ORM to give me people that don't have a `resume`. I've tried the following, but all fail to return the desired result:

```
>>> Person.objects.filter(resume=None)
[]
>>> Person.objects.filter(resume__exact=None)
[]
>>> Person.objects.filter(resume__isnull=True)
[]
```

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/844556/django-filter-how-do-i-go-about-filtering-for-emply-or-null-names-in-a-queryse

Comment: This isn't a duplicate, they're different questions.

Comment: This seems to be a different question, because it deals with FileFields which require a different solution because they are CharFields. It's good information. The other question doesn't discuss this situation.

Comment: Please define "fail".  Since we don't know what "fail" means, we can't really guess what's wrong with the sample questies.   Also ``file`` fields are special, since they're not actually **in** the database.

Comment: @S.Lott I've edited the question to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that you filter by empty string `''`

```
Person.objects.filter(resume='')
```

The underlying field is a `CharField()` as mentioned by the  [docs for `Filefield`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#filefield).

Django stores blanks for CharFields as empty strings not NULL, so filtering for empty strings gets you Persons with no resumes.

[`Model Field References regarding Null`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/fields/#null)

Comment: Thanks, that works for me. Will a `FileField` *ever* be `None`?

Comment: Check out the blog post [`here`](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/28/django-tips-difference-between-blank-and-null/)

Comment: The docs for `FileField` don't mention anything about having to check for an empty string rather than `None`, and neither does that blog post.

Comment: @bradly.ayers the docs talk about the underlying field as a CharField, and the blog talks about why null is stored as an empty string in the db for CharFields.

Comment: @kriegar Which paragraph in the blog post talks about that?

Comment: @bradly.ayers i should have just linked [`this`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/fields/#null) but the comments from that blog post discuss this issue. I guess the blog is another level removed from the underlying fact that blank CharFields are stored as empty strings. Sorry.

Comment: Please edit your answer to link to that null documentation as the rationale for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Person.objects.filter(resume__exact = None)
```

read the document here

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#id6

Comment: How is this any different to `Person.objects.filter(resume=None)`?