# Django: Elegant way to lookup a non-empty string

Tags: python, django, lookup

I have a model `Chair` with a blank-able `CharField` called `wood_type`.

I want to filter all the chairs with a `wood_type` which is not `''`.

What's an elegant way to do it with Django?

I can think of this:

```
Chair.objects.filter(~django.db.models.Q(wood_type=''))
```

Or this:

```
Chair.objects.filter(wood_type__regex='(.|\n)+')
```

But they're ugly as hell. Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/844556/django-filter-how-do-i-go-about-filtering-for-empty-or-null-names-in-a-querys

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Chair.objects.exclude(wood_type='')` should do the trick.

Comment: Sorry, used the OP's notation.

Comment: I personally don't like it... But marking as accepted anyway because I guess it's the best way there is in Django, in lieu of a new lookup type.

Answer (score 0):

exclude the empty string

```
Chair.objects.exclude(wood_type='')
```