# How to return default value if field is NULL?

Tags: python, django, orm

I need analog of sql IS_NULL function. In postgres, for example, I can write like this

`coalesce(field, 'Empty')`

How I can implement this using Django?

Comment: You mean... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/844556/django-filter-how-do-i-go-about-filtering-for-empty-or-null-names-in-a-querys?

Comment: Not exactly. I need replace all null values with deafult value. Not only detect them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra) queryset method:

```
MyModel.objects.extra(select={'field': "coalesce(field, 'Empty')"})
```

**COALESCE** should work similarly in most db engines.

Comment: its changing my float field to u'unicode'. I want float in return. how to?