# Django ORM command to get distinct values without empty fields

Tags: python, django

I am using a command like the foollwing to get all the distinct values of a column in a a table:

```
set(deg_course_cat.objects.values_list('degree_code', flat=True))
```

But the list also returns a `''` (empty slots) wherever they are present in the column. How do i give a command to get only the cells with values and not the NULL values?

Comment: Maybe you have empty strings in `degree_code` field not `NULL` Null usually is returned None.

Comment: you are right. Sorry about the wordings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filter them out

```
set((deg_course_cat.objects.filter(degree_code__isnull=False).values_list('degree_code', flat=True))
```

**EDIT**

Filter out empty and null results. SO question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844556/filtering-for-empty-or-null-names-in-a-queryset)

```
set(
 deg_course_cat.objects
 .exclude(degree_code__isnull=True)
 .exclude(degree_code__exact='')
 .values_list('degree_code', flat=True)
)
```

Comment: No luck with that! :(

Comment: Well, I don't have a django env here but, are you getting an error message ? (also, is it possible that you'r getting an empty string and not an actual null ? Cause in that case you should filter out empty results and not null results)

Comment: how do i do that? I think you are right. It must be empty results. How do i filter empty results? Sorry about my wordings