# Empty query returns all fields from database. Django

Tags: django

In the search form field, If I don't enter anything, but push on the button to search the query. The query returns every each field from the database.
    Company.objects.exclude(Q(name__isnull=True)).exclude(Q(name__exact=''))
Somehow, doesn't help me. If I use them together or separate.
The code in views.py is:

```
class className(listView)
    model=Company
    template_name='name_of_the_template.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        query=self.request.Get.get('q')
        query=query.replace('#',' ') //same for ?\/$%^+*()[] *tried to set exclude code here

        if query == ' ':
            object_list = Company.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains='None'))//sending to the empty object
            return object_list
    else:
        // *tried to set exclude code here
            object_list = Company.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=query))
            return object_list
```

None of exclude code helps. I believe I do simple mistake somewhere... because code suppose to work, but somehow still.
I just also tried to get rid off if else statement and use exclude statements for queries such as '', ' ' and null and after that filter for query... And now excluding queries for ' ' also doesn't work...

Django doesn't tell me the exclude doesn't work, all works, except, it is like not in the code.

Comment: Exactly what do yout to happen if the input is empty?

Comment: just would like it return nothing or query emty object, which is under name 'None' or replace '' with ' ' like it does with #... and then I send ' ' query to empty object.

Comment: if I try to query=query.replace('', ' ') then django gives me mistake

Comment: if I set space once in the search field, the code works and sends user to empty object, but if I don't enter anything in the search field, but just push "search", it gives me every field from database...

Comment: yes because then query is `''` (the empty string), and thus `else` will be triggered, and each element "contains" the empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't enter anything, then the string is empty `''`, or it is `None` if no parameter is passed. You can thus check the *truthiness* of `query`, you probably however better first `.strip()` the string to remove any leading or trailing spaces:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    query = self.request.Get.get('q')
    if query is not None:
        query = query.replace('#',' ')
        query = query.strip()
    if not query:
        return Company.objects.none()
    else:
        return Company.objects.filter(name__icontains=query)
```

In the template, you can then use a [**`{% for … %}…{% empty %}…{% endfor %}`** template block [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for-empty):

```
{% for object in object_list %}
    {{ object }}
{% empty %}
    no objects found!
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thank you... if you don't mind... I saw everybody advise to use exclude code, and exact code... why it didn't work for me?

Comment: @bugthefifth: where did you see that advice? `.exclude()` is used to filter *out* elements that satisfy the condition (just like `.filter(..)` is used to filter *in* all elements that satisfy the condition).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844556/filtering-for-empty-or-null-names-in-a-queryset

Comment: @bugthefifth: but that means if you want to return values for which `name` *is* `NULL`, or `name` *is* the empty string `''`, or as in the question, filter these out.

Comment: may be I didn't understand something... but I went through couple of other places, same advices... again, may be I am mistaken for some reason? and I ddin't look for the right answer...

Comment: I see... Sure I knew that something in my understanding is off, just make sure that I completely understand it now. Thank you!

Comment: Willem, thank you for the complete and efficient answer!