# Django queryset filter empty JSONField

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-jsonfield

I would like to filter a JSONField `my_field`where the JSon is not empty. In the documentation there are `has_key`and `has_any_key` methods but I don't know the possible keys in advance. In SQL it should be something like:

```sql
select * from my_model where cardinality(my_field)>0;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844556/filtering-for-empty-or-null-names-in-a-queryset

Comment: This filter null value. I want to filter empty json (json with a size of 0)

Answer (score 4):

Found a way to achieve using `iexact`:

```
MyObject.objects.filter(my_field__iexact="{}")
```

Answer (score 0):

according to [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#querying-jsonfield) you can use

```
MyModel.objects.include(myjsonfield__exact=[])
MyModel.objects.exclude(myjsonfield__exact=[])
```